# Global counter inside an Android App

Tags: java, android

So I've recently written an application that calculates tip and I wanted to implement a global (global as in everyone who uses the app) counter for every time a tip is calculated. I have a function that I can easily implement and upload to somewhere to keep a global counter for everyone using an app. The problem is I just don't full understand how I would go about doing this. I'm thinking in terms of this,

If 3G data is on -> upload count to x (server or file online)
If 3G data is off -> add a count to file on local device -> if file exists (when 3G is turned back on and app is launched) upload count from file and delete file.

I guess my question would be where would I get some more information on this and/or how would I go about doing something like this?

I appreciate any help, I'm sorry if the question is a bit vague I just can't seem to put a wording on what I wanted to get done.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to local part right...

> If 3G data is on -> upload count to x (server or file online) If 3G data is off -> add a count to file on local device -> if file exists (when 3G is turned back on and app is launched) upload count from file and delete file.

I would probably store that count in a preference instead of a stand alone file for ease but it can go anywhere. As for the server side, a simple web service (I've used PHP) can receive counts and increment a local counter.

However, I am betting there is a nice analytics library like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) that you can use that will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: I second what Andrew said about storing it in a database and using a webservice. As an additional hint about checking network connectivity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll definitely give Flurry a look at and try to integrate it. It's awesome that these types of resources are available.

@Gabe- thanks for the network connectivity link that helped out a bit. Will post back if I run into anymore problems.

Comment: Thanks again, I have gotten Flurry set up properly and handling events for what I need. The only problem I'm running into now is parsing the xml code with java which I'll post in another question. Also, Flurry handles events offline and uploads them when data is connected again so no extra code needed! =D